# Critical Structure Corruption Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, memory, drivers

I keep getting this error "Critical Structure Corruption" and can't seem to fix it.

It happens while I am busy on my laptop. Here are some of the steps I have tried so far to resolve this with no success.

1. Ran Windows Memory Diagnostic = no problems so RAM looks good.
2. Check The CPU with Intel-Processor-Diagnostic-Tool = PASS all
3. Drivers update, I used driver booster and did need to update 18 drivers but was able to update with no issues.
4. Update software and drivers, well it was suggested that I update BlueStacks but the update failed, bluestacks mentioned that it might be an issue so as I do not use the tool I uninstalled the software altogether.
5. Updated Windows, this I do regularly and automatically so no big updates were missed.
6. Defragged the machine - system is optimized
7. Ran anti-virus check and all's good
8. Ran CCleaner

Now I might mention I'm not a super user, but I'm able to follow suggestions quite well.

Any help will be appreciated.

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: You should add a screenshot of the error.

Comment: I assume you are getting this bugcheck - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x109---critical-structure-corruption.  Do you have at least a minidump under %systemroot%\Minidump

Comment: Hi I have not seen that bugcheck.

Comment: It's on the screenshot.  Do you have a dump file?

Comment: hi yes i do, it it 911MB

Comment: Can you download the Windows SDK [https://developer.microsoft.com/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk] and install just the Debugging Tools for Windows. 

Once done you need to configure symbols in Windbg.  File menu - Setting: `SRV*C:\debug*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols` will do, having created C:\debug.  Once you have that setup you can choose to open the crash dump.  Once done run the command: `!analyze -v` If you can paste the contents of the command window in maybe a pastebin and reference it here that would help.

Comment: I wanted to ask if my dump file isn't too large?

Comment: Depends what type, what is your default dump type set to? https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/254649/overview-of-memory-dump-file-options-for-windows .Based on the size I'd say it's a kernel dump or possibly the new automatic dump type from a computer with 2GB RAM?  Either way it doesn't matter, typically the bigger the better for debugging :)

Comment: here you go, https://pastebin.com/fSa3b9QX thanks for the help so far.

Comment: huh, just may be offtopic, but is it easier for you to just reinstall windows? :) it can solve that, I guess.

Comment: Thanks for that.  Not much of a call stack to go on but we at least know from the 4th parameter being 0x19, that it is an issue with "Loaded module list modification".  As it's a corruption and you have tested the RAM.  The next step would be to try and understand if there is a dodgy driver causing the corruption which seems most likely.   Can you run verifier.exe - Choose "Create standard settings" ->  "select driver names from a list" -> Sort all drivers by "Provider". Select all apart from Microsoft drivers. Finish and restart. When it next crashes can you analyze that dump in the same way?

Comment: Also, if you could provide the output of `lmv` to show loaded modules that would be good.

Comment: I followed your steps, ended up resetting windows. No issues yet today and my pc have been on an entire day.  Should I wait for the next BSOD?

Answer (score -1):

Verify the integrity of the system files, Windows Update and the self checks you've described just patch the system and diagnose hardware.

Reboot and logon as an admin or execute an system file checker from an admin prompt:

```
sfc /scannow
```

That can take a while, the process is self corrective so issues will be fixed automatically for you.

Then, check for additional corruption while online by verifying and replacing any corrupt files directly from Microsoft.com

```
dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth
```

Be prepared to uninstall some applications such as "system accelerators" that claim to improve computer performance but really just attempt to replace drivers. Like that "Driver Booster" you mentioned, driver aggregators like what that sounds like aren't really industry accepted and well known or used by enterprise users and it sounds dubious in itself,  did these errors occur before you installed "Driver Booster"?

Comment: Hi, no I installed the booster as part of a step by step I found on a blog post. I also uninstalled it right after. I ran both commands and I got error 87 with dism when I wanted to run SFC I got a message saying there is already another software running a scan and I should continue afterward. Can you suggest a better tool to check the drivers please.

Comment: @Beven, You ran SFC /scannow and DISM simultaneously?Downloading third party tools to fix ambiguous Windows errors can just distract, detect irrelevant minor issues or make things even worse. Understandably if you're uninitiated and just want it to work right those tools are tempting Google results but running down the integrity of the OS can fix a vast majority of these problems.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, will be more careful in the future.

Comment: Ok, I ran the dism command with CheckHealth & RestoreHealth and it completed successfully during the SFC scannow I got another BCOD same error and then ran the SFC again did not find any integrity violations.